# How to make a function that gives probabilities in a Geometric distribution?

Tags: matlab, function, probability, probability-distribution

I'm using MATLAB to make a function that returns the probability mass function (PMF) for a Geometric distribution when I enter the values of p, q, and the number of attempts (x) as the inputs.

My function:

```
function Probability = Geometric(p, q, x)
Probability = p*q^x-1
```

Now whenever I try to calculate the probability by typing in the values of **p**, **q**, and **x**, such as:

```
Geometric(0.5, 0.5, 1),
```

The exact error:

> Geometric(0.5,0.5,1)
>
> ??? Undefined function or method 'Geometric' for input arguments of type 'double'.

I've tried changing functions, and reducing them to one input and one output.

I expect the probabilities to be calculated, but they just don't.

Answer (score 2):

**What's going wrong?**

```
p*q^x-1       % Your original code
```

Your original code is taking `q`, raising it the `x`th power, multiplying it by `p`, *then* subtracting 1. This is equivalent to the following code which you certainly didn't intend.

```
(p*(q^x)) - 1     % What your code was doing written differently
```

Considering [**order of operations**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/operator-precedence.html), the correction is easy.

```
p*q^(x-1)         % Your corrected code
```

Another *possible* error source is your function is not saved as a standalone m-file "Geometric.m" which must also be on your MATLAB path (MATLAB has to "see" it). If you have your function file "**MyFunction.m**" stored in a folder, you can add that folder to MATLAB's visible path with one line (or manually navigate there). For more details, see [how to create a function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html).

```
mypathtoMyFunction = 'C:\Users\SonnyJordan\Documents\SweetCode\FunctionFolder';
path(path,'mypathtoMyFunction')
```

**A Full Solution (3 approaches)**
From your parameterization of the [Geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution), you're wanting the support on {1, 2, 3, 4, ...}.

Two things. **(1)** I'd recommend an [anonymous function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) for something like this. **(2)** There really isn't a need to separate *p* and *q* as separate variables since *p* + *q* = 1 and therefore one determines the other (i.e. `q = 1-p`).

**Approach 1: Anonymous function**

```
% MATLAB R2018b
geopmfh =@(p,k) p.*((1-p).^(k-1));     % Define pmf
k = 5;                                 % Number of trials
p = 0.2;                               % Prob("Success" on trial)
geopmfh(p,k)                           % Probability
```

Above code is fully [vectorized](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) so you could pass it vectors and/or arrays of inputs.

A quick check to validate it is a valid [probability mass function (pmf)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function).

```
M = 500;     
sum(geopmfh(p,[1:M]))                % should return 1 if M large enough
```

**Approach 2: Function (w/ error checking)**
As an aside, making a function in MATLAB would make a lot of sense if you wanted to add error checking on the function inputs to ensure *k* is a positive integer and that *p* is between [0 1].

```
function [pmf] = geopmf(p,k)
%GEOPMF Calculates pmf for Geometric(p,k) distribution on {1,2,3,...}
%     pmf = geopmf(p,k)
%       p = n x d matrix of n d-dimensional success probabilities; must be [0,1]
%       k = m x d matrix of m d-dimensional numbers of trials
%     pmf = n x m matrix of probabilities 
%
% Examples:
% k = 4; p = .5;
% pmf = geopmf(p,k)   %  pmf = 0.0625      

% Input Error Checking ****************************************************
if isempty(p) | isempty(k), pmf = []; return, end
if nargin ~= 2, error('Function requires two inputs.'), end
if p < 0 | p > 1, error('p must be between 0 and 1.'), end
if k < 1 | ~isint(k), error('k must be positive integer & k > 0.'), end   % with this parameterization

n = size(p,1); d = size(p,2);
m = size(k,1); 
if isempty(p) | ~isnumeric(p) | ~ismatrix(p)
    error('p must be non-empty numeric scalar, vector, or 2-D matrix.');
elseif isempty(k) | ~isnumeric(k) | ~ismatrix(k) 
    error('k must be non-empty numeric scalar, vector, or 2-D matrix.');
elseif size(k,2) ~=d
    error('Rows of p and k must have same dimensions.');
end
% End (Input Error Checking) **********************************************

pmf = p.*((1-p).^(k-1));
end
```

**Approach 3: MATLAB's built-in function**
If you have the Statistics toolbox, MATLAB has a function for this already called [`geopdf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/geopdf.html) but note it is parameterized according to the other "version" with support {0, 1, 2, ...} (see [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution)).

```
p.*((1-p).^k)          % The other parameterization
geopdf(k,p)            % Note order of inputs
```

You can correct for that by adjusting your input.

```
geopdf(k-1,p)          % Subtract 1 trial
```

---

Code tested with MATLAB R2018b.