# How to sample from delayed geometric distribution in matlab

Tags: matlab, distribution, sampling

What is the best and correct way to sample from a delayed geometric distribution (geometric distribution for positive integers greater 0) in matlab?

To my understanding the delayed geometric distribution is defined as follows, where `f` is the probability mass function:

```
f(k)= (1-p)*p^(k-1) for k=1,2,3... and 0<p<1
```

My current approach to sample from that distribution is to first solve for k and defining a function that returns a random value:

```
function k = georndDel(p)
    f = rand;
    k = log(-(f*p)./(p-1))./log(p); %for log(p)<>0, 0<p<1
end
```

However, this returns a continuous value, sometimes negative, where I require only positive integers to be returned.

Is there amn obvious error in inverting the probability mass function? And how do I restrict the random values to positive ingegers?

Comment: So you want to generate _random_ values _with_ that distribution, or to _compute_ values _of_ the pmf? Also, do you have access to the Statistics Toolbox?

Comment: thank you for your comment. I want to generate _random_ values _with_ that distribution. And I do have access to the Statistics Toolbox. Does that simplify things?

Comment: See [`geornd`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/geornd.html). I think you need to add `1` to the results and replace the input `p` by `1-p`, according to your definition of the pmf. This is because the pmf used by `geornd` is `p*(1-p)^k` (same as [`geopdf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/geopdf.html))

Comment: As LuisMendo pointed out, the parameterization (using `p` versus `1-p`) depends on if your Geometric random variable starts at 1 (e.g., 1, 2, 3, ...) or 0 (e.g., 0, 1, 2, ...). See "Approach 3" [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55912990/8239061) for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate the numbers manually:

```
cdf_val = rand();

k = log(1-cdf_val)/log(1-p);
k = round(k+0.5);
```

Or as Luis already mentioned using the geornd() plus 1.

Here is an example:

```
p = 0.1;

n = 20000;

arr1=zeros(n, 1);
arr2=zeros(n, 1);

for i=1:n
    % manual approach
    cdf_val = rand();

    k = log(1-cdf_val)/log(1-p);
    arr1(i) = round(k+0.5);

    % using geornd
    arr2(i) = geornd(p)+1;
end

histogram(arr1, 0:60);
hold on;
histogram(arr2, 0:60);
hold off;
legend('manual', 'geornd+1')
```

[image: generating delayed geometric distribution manually]